# XCode-LLDB when attaching to process in simulator the breakpoints don't work

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints, lldb

I have an issue in certain code only when built for "production".

This problem doesn't occur when in debug mode (Hitting the "Play" button to run the app).

So in order to debug this problem, I compiled the app and loaded to simulator. The problem does indeed reproduce as expected.

In XCode I can successfully attach to the running process by doing: Debug->Attach to process by PID or name" from my source code.

I am able to run commands in the LLDB console so I know that the debugger is connected to the app, but none of my breakpoints are working.

How is it possible to make the breakpoints work as expected in order to debug this issue?

Comment: Are the breakpoints getting set at all?  To figure this out, issue the "break list" command in Xcode's debugger console.  Does that show the breakpoints you are expecting to hit?

Comment: I'm encountering this issue as well. Specifically, building with Buck and running in the simulator. I can view the "View Debugger" and see the memory usage, etc but can't hit any set debugger breakpoints.